# Autocomplete script getting Object expected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

At the url http://www.candyundies.com/template_non_product.php, I am using an autocomplete script on the search box for suggestions. I have tested and is working in current versions of Chrome, Safari, Opera, Firefox and IE 8. However, I noticed in IE 8, it is throwing an Object expected error after the first letter is typed in the search box but the script continues to work flawlessly. I'm sure it is a syntax error or something small I have overlooked but I cannot seem to find the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Contents of autocomplete.js:

```
// global variables
var acListTotal   =  0;
var acListCurrent = -1;
var acDelay       = 100;
var acURL         = null;
var acSearchId    = null;
var acResultsId   = null;
var acSearchField = null;
var acResultsDiv  = null;
function setAutoComplete(field_id, results_id, get_url) {
// initialize vars
acSearchId  = "#" + field_id;
acResultsId = "#" + results_id;
acURL       = get_url;
// create the results div
$("#auto").append('<div id="' + results_id + '"></div>');
// register mostly used vars
acSearchField   = $(acSearchId);
acResultsDiv    = $(acResultsId);
// on blur listener
acSearchField.blur(function(){ setTimeout("clearAutoComplete()", 100) });
// on key up listener
acSearchField.keyup(function (e) {
    // get keyCode (window.event is for IE)
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || window.event.keyCode;
    var lastVal = acSearchField.val();
    // check an treat up and down arrows
    if(updownArrow(keyCode)){
        return;
    }
    // check for an ENTER or ESC
    if(keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 27){
        clearAutoComplete();
        return;
    }
    // if is text, call with delay
    setTimeout(function () {autoComplete(lastVal)}, acDelay);
});
}
// treat the auto-complete action (delayed function)
function autoComplete(lastValue) {
// get the field value
var part = acSearchField.val();
// if it's empty clear the resuts box and return
if(part == ''){
    clearAutoComplete();
    return;
}
// if it's equal the value from the time of the call, allow
if(lastValue != part){
    return;
}
// get remote data as JSON
$.getJSON(acURL + part, function(json){
    // get the total of results
    var ansLength = acListTotal = json.length;
    // if there are results populate the results div
    if(ansLength > 0){
        var newData = '';
        // create a div for each result
        for(i=0; i < ansLength; i++) {
            newData += '<div class="unselected">' + json[i] + '</div>';
        }
        // update the results div
        acResultsDiv.html(newData);
        acResultsDiv.css("display","block");
        // for all divs in results
        var divs = $(acResultsId + " > div");
        // on mouse over clean previous selected and set a new one
        divs.mouseover( function() {
            divs.each(function(){ this.className = "unselected"; });
            this.className = "selected";
        });
        // on click copy the result text to the search field and hide
        divs.click( function() {
            acSearchField.val(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            clearAutoComplete();
        });
    } else {
        clearAutoComplete();
    }
});
}
// clear auto complete box
function clearAutoComplete() {
acResultsDiv.html('');
acResultsDiv.css("display","none");
}
// treat up and down key strokes defining the next selected element
function updownArrow(keyCode) {
if(keyCode == 40 || keyCode == 38){
    if(keyCode == 38){ // keyUp
        if(acListCurrent == 0 || acListCurrent == -1){
            acListCurrent = acListTotal-1;
        }else{
            acListCurrent--;
        }
    } else { // keyDown
        if(acListCurrent == acListTotal-1){
            acListCurrent = 0;
        }else {
            acListCurrent++;
        }
    }
    // loop through each result div applying the correct style
    acResultsDiv.children().each(function(i){
        if(i == acListCurrent){
            acSearchField.val(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            this.className = "selected";
        } else {
            this.className = "unselected";
        }
    });
    return true;
} else {
    // reset
    acListCurrent = -1;
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: "request(this.value) - onkeyup function is set for input#term, but I couldn't see "request()" function is implemented, remove it and try again, I think you forgot to remove it. It's breaking javascript proccess.

Comment: Awesome that was the problem. Thanks so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. See comment by ocanal.